# How to install Dell OpenManage without having an KVM over IP

Tags: dell, installation, dell-openmanage

That is pretty much the question. I just have ssh access to my server, and need to install Dell OpenManage in order to be able to monitor my server which is in colo.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need access to the OS itself, or at least a command line to install it.

In a similar fashion, I was able to install OpenManage on my Hyper-V Server that doesn't have a GUI, and I was able to install using the command line. Granted, i was sitting directly at the console, though.

[This](http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2009/11/setting-up-dell-openmanage-on-hyper-v-server-2008-r2/) article will get you just about all the way.

Comment: As my server is far way, consul is the only access that I have. Can you please elaborate a bit on how to do so? I assume I need to download OpenMange iso, then what should I do?

Comment: Thank Dan, I think I found the right docs for my OS: http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/deb/latest/

Comment: You should have mentioned your OS in the question.